# Trouble assigning a variable to display the index of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program where I generate 100 random numbers, I prompt the user to enter a number, and the program says the number was found at index XX. Or that the number was not found. Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class lab1
{
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    //Let's create an array with 100 random numbers
    int [] randomArray = new int [100];
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();


    for(int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++)
    {
        randomArray[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(100) + 1;
    }
//ask user to enter a number between 1 and 100
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int searchNumber;

    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 100 to search 
for: ");
    searchNumber = input.nextInt();

    boolean found = false;


    for(int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(searchNumber == randomArray[i])
        {
            found = true;
            break;//Exits the loop
        }
    }
    if(found)
    {
        System.out.println("We have found your number, " + searchNumber + " 
at index " + index);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("We did not find your number");
    }
}
}
```

I am not able to get the index to display when my program finds a number, I know this is because the variable "i" is only defined within the for loop. I am not sure how to create a new variable outside of the for loop and assign i to that variable inside the for loop.

Comment: as of JDK 8 you can generate _100_ random numbers between 0-100 inclusive easily as such [**`int[] randomNumbers = new Random().ints(100,0,101).toArray();`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare `i` outside the loop i.e.

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

then you can use the index `i` within your `println`.

```
if(found)
{
     System.out.println("We have found your number, " + searchNumber + "at index " + i);
}
else
{
     System.out.println("We did not find your number");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea all along, and even articulated it perfectly:  "...create a new variable outside of the for loop and assign `i` to that variable inside the for loop":

```
    int foundAt = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(searchNumber == randomArray[i])
        {
            foundAt = i;
            break;//Exits the loop
        }
    }
    if(foundAt != -1)
    {
        System.out.println("We have found your number, " + searchNumber + " 
at index " + foundAt);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("We did not find your number");
    }
}
```